# Owning the domain used in my application bundle ID

Tags: android, google-play, bundle-identifier

When releasing an app on Google Play, it has to have a unique bundle id such as com.example.myapp Like explained here: [Bundle ID in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705874/bundle-id-in-android/)

But how important is it to own the domain that I use in my bundle ID? Is it even recommended? E.g., if I use com.example.myapp, should I register/own the domain example.com?

Comment: NO, it isn't necessary. It can be whatever: after all, it's only a **name**.

Comment: Here is more info about why IDs looks like domains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475168/what-is-the-significance-of-the-reverse-domain-name-for-java-package-structure And this answer for similar question for java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166051/how-should-i-name-packages-if-i-dont-have-a-domain-associated-with-me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is first important to know what the Bundle ID is used for. An applications bundle ID is used as a name for the application when published to the Google Play Store.

In answer to your question, **it is not important that you own the domain in your Bundle ID** not everyone has a domain and you don't need one to create an application. It is just a unique identifier for 1. your company or person(s) developing the application and 2. the application.

Comment: I don't own any domain name. How to come up with unique package names. Say for example, if i create a package with name com.pradeep.quizapp, there are plenty of chances that there could be a app in play store already with this name. How to come up unique package names ?? Any guidelines and tips ??

Comment: Good question. Using your name is usally a good place to start but you might have a very common name e.g. Ben or Peter. So try using a username you might go by. You mentioned [com.pradeep.quizapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pradeep.quizapp). As you can see from the link, there is no such application made 'public' on the Play Store, feel free to replace the `id` in the URL to check the ID you want to use. I believe best practises are a matter of personal opinion, so just do a quick Google Search and find out what other people think.

Answer (score 6):

There is no technical requirement to own the domain for the package name / bundle id / application id.

However some prefixes are blocked by google, like com.google (for obvious reasons) and com.example (to prevent people who don't know what they are doing uploading sample code).

And if you try to use an id that obviously belongs to someone else, eg com.facebook, then you might be banned for abuse for attempted impersonation. So it is always better to use your own domain.